# Qt 5.1 and Mac: Bug making macdeployqt not working properly

Tags: macos, qt, macdeployqt

I have a problem since the version `5.1rc2` of `Qt` for Mac OS X. (5.1 is also affected, not the 5.1rc1)
When I build my app and do a `otool -L` on the binary file to see the paths of the shared libraries, I get: (it's just a sample, I removed some of them for clarity)

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit 
    (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1187.37.0)
/Users/chris/**Qt5.1.0//5.1.0**/clang_64/lib/QtWebKitWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebKitWidgets
    (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
/Users/chris/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick
    (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
/Users/chris/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtQml.framework/Versions/5/QtQml
    (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
/Users/chris/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork
    (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
/Users/chris/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
    (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
/Users/chris/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui
    (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
```

As you can see there is a double slash in the paths of the Qt libraries.
When I use macdeployqt to deploy my app, those paths aren't changed to local frameworks (@executable_path/../Frameworks/...), because of this...
I have to do it manually with the install_name_tool, and it's really annoying.

What can I do to fix this? (I've tried re-installing Qt, cleaning, runing qmake again and rebuilding without change)

Comment: How did you install Qt? If you can specify a path anywhere, I'd try with `/Users/chris/Qt5.1.0` instead of `/Users/chris/Qt5.1.0/`. Otherwise it looks like a Qt bug that you should report in the Qt bug tracker.

Comment: With the official installer (http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.1/5.1.0/qt-mac-opensource-5.1.0-clang-offline.dmg). I didn't find any way to modify it, when I choose the Qt location it was "/Users/chris/Qt5.1.0"

Comment: Can confirm this is happening. Worked great in RC1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

having the same issue. I applied next workaround:

after I build my program, I've changed links inside exe to a right ones

```
install_name_tool -change /Users/username/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick  /Users/username/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick <YourExecutable>
```

After this workaround macdeployqt has changed all links inside exe to a relative ones.

But my App became broken. The thing is that I've added all my images and QML files into resources. After I ran macdeployqt - I can not run my app. When I ran this with gdb - I see next error:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component 
qrc:/qml/main.qml:-1 File not found

Error: Your root item has to be a Window.
```

So somehow all my resources became unavailable. Does anyone know how to fix that?

I also started a discussion on [qt forum](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/29805/)

**UPDATE, HOW TO DEPLOY:**

1. Use [this script](https://gist.github.com/lasconic/5965542) to get rid of double slashes inside dynamic linking paths.

   ./fixqt.sh ~/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64
2. Build macdeployqt tool from this [repository](https://github.com/MaximAlien/macdeployqtfixed).
3. Run macdeployqt and specify dir with your qml source:

   macdeployqt MyApp.app/ -qmldir=../src/qml -dmg

After those steps I managed to run my application on different OS X system, without QT Installed. I've added all my qml files and images into resources. QtQuick and QtQuick.2 modules copied inside MyApp.app/Content/MacOS/

Hope it helps

Comment: Did the same thing and I also got an issue :( (with Qxt)

Comment: @user1494428 could you please describe what kind of issues did you get after you modifies links manually?

Comment: If I recall correctly (I'm in holidays) the issue is that the Qxt libs also require Qt so we have to modify the path of the Qt libs for each one. After doing that my app crashes. I don't remember the crash content, but I don't think it was very explicit. I'm hoping they'll fix it in the next version of Qt...

Comment: I have reported bugs to QT:
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32379#comment-209257
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32380

Comment: Thanks, I've selected this as answer, waiting for this issue to be fixed by the Qt developers.

Comment: OK, there are still troubles even with this work around. The thing is that there are a lot of dependencies between Qt libraries. For example QtQML depends on Network, Core, V8 ( you can check that by running otool -L ). So QtQML links with them dynamically. macdeployqt suppose to resolve linking paths, from absolute once to relatives. Because we copied all libs inside app bundle. But it does not do it, because of doble slash inside paths for QtQml for example:

`otool -L QtQml 
/Users/username/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork )`

Comment: I'm on 5.1.1 and this still seems broken to me.  I can get all the libs fixed (i think), but when I run I still get all the QML modules missing.  I'm guessing this: "QtQuick and QtQuick.2 modules copied inside MyApp.app/Content/MacOS/" fixes it, but what does it mean?

Answer (score 6):

I'm posting this as a solution as I just lost (another) day to this process with 5.3 (and I assume it is the same for 5.4).

`macdeployqt` now works as intended but the failed piece of documentation here is that you need to specify and ***absolute path*** to each qml directory (relative might work but I've had no luck at all).

Here's how I solved that for my release process:

In the project file I now have

```
  mac {
    CONFIG += x86
    CONFIG += c++11
    #Disable these for development
    QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.9 #I'm not sure I need this
    QMAKE_POST_LINK = {path to macdeployqt}/macdeployqt {appname}.app -qmldir=$$PWD/qml/{appname}/ -verbose=3
  }
```

This effectively calls:
`macdeployqt appname.app - /path/to/source/code/appname/qml/appname/ -verbose=3`

When the absolute path is specified it appears to work fine but when I use a relative path I run into several problems. `PWD` is the source directory and the executables are run from the build directory. The absolute path of the build is `OUT_PWD`.

The beauty of keeping this in the release configuration in the project is that I debug normally (no app package) and the release package correctly builds from creator. Theoretically I can just wrap that into a Jenkins build and be done with this headache once and for all.

***The Short Answer***

`macdeployqt` MUST SCAN your qml files if you're using them otherwise the imports will be broken and you'll see errors like:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/qml/LightAssistant.qml:5 module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed
qrc:/qml/LightAssistant.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed
qrc:/qml/LightAssistant.qml:4 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:/qml/LightAssistant.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed
qrc:/qml/LightAssistant.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Layouts" is not installed
```

Finally, my directory structure looks like this:

```
  Project
    - qml
      - appname
        files1.qml
        files2.qml
        ...
        filesX.qml 
    - js
    - images
```

These then get packaged into the Resource file which, by definition, are not copied to the build directory and thus macdeployqt can't scan them unless the pathing is perfect. By using this build process I have a step in my build (release) that just deals with it and I don't have to run `macdeployqt` when I'm debugging. Keep in mind if you use the app_bundle you need to run macdeployqt on each build which will really mess with your debugging workflow.

Answer (score 4):

This thread:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/55277-Qt-5-1-and-Mac-Bug-making-macdeployqt-not-working-properly

contains this link:

https://gist.github.com/lasconic/5965542

to this script by lasconic (not my work):

```
BIN_FILE=YOURBINARY
for P in `otool -L $BIN_FILE | awk '{print $1}'` 
do 
    if [[ "$P" == *//* ]] 
    then 
        PSLASH=$(echo $P | sed 's,//,/,g')
        install_name_tool -change $P $PSLASH $BIN_FILE
    fi 
done 

QTDIR=$1
for F in `find $QTDIR/lib $QTDIR/plugins $QTDIR/qml  -perm 755 -type f` 
do 
    for P in `otool -L $F | awk '{print $1}'`
    do   
        if [[ "$P" == *//* ]] 
        then 
            PSLASH=$(echo $P | sed 's,//,/,g')
            install_name_tool -change $P $PSLASH $F
        fi 
     done
done
```

You just need to replace `YOURBINARY` with e.g. `myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp`

And `QTDIR=$1` with `QTDIR=/Users/MyName/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64`

Save the file in the same dir as myapp.app

And run it with

```
sh thankslasconic.sh
```

then you can run

```
macdeployqt myapp.app
```

and it should work. For me it did. That is why I am posting it here.

Comment: This solution don't work if you are using QtQuick 2.0, atleast my mac wouldn't work

Comment: The thing is that it looks like macdeployqt does not handle QtQuick modules. So I guess at the moment QtQuick modules has to be copied manually.

I'm straggling with the same issue, my app is using QtQuick.Components and so on. Can't get it work at the moment.

Comment: OK, here is the bug for that https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29495

Answer (score 1):

I think its a installer bug. All librarys and tool (compiled/linked by installer?) referenced to .../Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/... (with double slash)

I've tried online and offline installer for Mac with the same result.

I've reported it as a bug.
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32467

Answer (score 1):

Just as a follow-up, this bug appears to be fixed in Qt5.1.1
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32365

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this site http://www.stringcat.com/company_blog/2013/07/04/failed-to-load-platform-cocoa/
See https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/blacktulipconfidence/branches/GuiDemoMac/ at the end of this page.

Comment: Don't just post links. If those links die, your answer becomes completely useless. Quote the relevant content and include the link as a source.

Comment: The procedures are very complicated and verbose, deploy Qt5 apps on mac is no much different than finding trouble for yourself, looks like I should go back to Qt4 before Qt5 solve the problem of macdeploy

Answer (score 0):

Tried all of the above with qt 5.1.1 but always got this crash:

```
QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const + 161
QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration() + 1763
QGuiApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher() + 28
QCoreApplication::init() + 101
QCoreApplication::QCoreApplication(QCoreApplicationPrivate&) + 42
```

so I created this elixir, YMMV:

1) get the above mentioned mostly kinda working macqtdeploy from [github](https://github.com/MaximAlien/macdeployqt).

2) build this new macqtdeploy

3) add this to main.cpp for mac os x only. this stuffs "-platformpluginpath" into argv before starting qapplication.

```
int macStart(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QFileInfo fi(argv[0]);
    QDir plugd(fi.dir());
    plugd.cdUp();
    plugd.cd("PlugIns");
    QString plugins = plugd.absolutePath();
    qDebug() << "PlugIns" << plugins;

    char* argv_sub[argc + 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        char* temp = (char*) malloc(strlen(argv[i]) + 1);
        strcpy(temp, argv[i]);
        argv_sub[i] = temp;
    }

    char ppp[255];
    strcpy(ppp, "-platformpluginpath");
    argv_sub[argc] = ppp;

    char pathx[2048];
    strcpy(pathx, (char*) plugd.absolutePath().toLocal8Bit().constData());
    argv_sub[argc + 1] = pathx;

    DCApplication app(argc + 2, argv_sub);
    app.startup();
    return app.exec();
}
```

4) build app

5) run new macqtdeploy on app

6) goodness

Answer (score 0):

set plugin folder to libraryPaths

```
QStringList paths;
paths.append("folder with plugins"); //can be inside bundle
QApplication::setLibraryPaths(paths);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always ended up in this discussion when looking for a similar error with macdeployqt and QT Quick 2.0 using QML.

The error I found was this:

`Machine:MacOS MyName$ ./tool 
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component qrc:/main.qml:1 plugin cannot be 
loaded for module "QtQuick": '/Users/thorstenbux/DAQRI/gitHub/artoolkit6/Source/Utilities/ImageDBSerialiser/build-ui/imageDatabase.app/Contents/PlugIns/quick/libqtquick2plugin.dylib' 
is not a valid Mach-O binary (not a dynamic library)`

and this:

`ERROR: Could not parse otool output: "/Users/myname/DAQRI/gitHub/tool/Source/Utilities/tool/build-tool-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_clang_64bit-Release/tool.app/Contents/PlugIns/quick/libqtquick2plugin.dylib:\n"`

I created a separate question for that kind of error here:
[QT Quick (QML) assemble mac-.bundle -> not a dynamic library error when using macdeployqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522830/qt-quick-qml-assemble-mac-bundle-not-a-dynamic-library-error-when-using-ma)

Just in case someone has the same issue and reads this thread.