# Qt 5.1rc1 Deployment on mac OS X, how could I deploy a simple QtQuick2 apps?

Tags: qt, qml

Why rc1 but not release version?Because the macdeploy of release version has more bugs than rc1

The qml is very simple

```
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle{
width: 400
height: 300
color: "black"
}
```

my .pro

```
QT += core gui qml quick

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
main.cpp

OTHER_FILES += \
main.qml
```

But I can't even deploy this simple app

My scrips

```
#******copy main.qml into the bundle**********
cp /Users/Qt/program/experiment_apps_and_libs/qmlTest2/main.qml /Users/Qt/program/experiment_apps_and_libs/qmlTest2/qmlTest2.app/Contents/MacOs

#*******create the folder and copy the plugins into the bundle**********
mkdir qmlTest2.app/Contents/PlugIns
mkdir qmlTest2.app/Contents/PlugIns/QtQuick

mkdir qmlTest2.app/Contents/PlugIns/QtQuick/LocalStorage
cp /Users/yyyy/Qt5.1.0RC1/5.1.0-rc1/clang_64/qml/QtQuick/LocalStorage/libqmllocalstorageplugin.dylib qmlTest2.app/Contents/PlugIns/QtQuick/LocalStorage
cp /Users/yyyy/Qt5.1.0RC1/5.1.0-rc1/clang_64/qml/QtQuick/LocalStorage/plugins.qmltypes qmlTest2.app/Contents/PlugIns/QtQuick/LocalStorage
cp /Users/yyyy/Qt5.1.0RC1/5.1.0-rc1/clang_64/qml/QtQuick/LocalStorage/qmldir qmlTest2.app/Contents/PlugIns/QtQuick/LocalStorage

mkdir qmlTest2.app/Contents/PlugIns/QtQuick.2
cp /Users/yyyy/Qt5.1.0RC1/5.1.0-rc1/clang_64/qml/QtQuick.2/libqtquick2plugin.dylib qmlTest2.app/Contents/PlugIns/QtQuick.2
cp /Users/yyyy/Qt5.1.0RC1/5.1.0-rc1/clang_64/qml/QtQuick.2/plugins.qmltypes qmlTest2.app/Contents/PlugIns/QtQuick.2
cp /Users/yyyy/Qt5.1.0RC1/5.1.0-rc1/clang_64/qml/QtQuick.2/qmldir qmlTest2.app/Contents/PlugIns/QtQuick.2

#**********call macdeployqt***************
macdeployqt /Users/Qt/program/experiment_apps_and_libs/qmlTest2/qmlTest2.app -verbose=3
```

I run otool -L on every plugins I added, all of them become relative path after macdeployqt

When I run the program by lldb, it always give me the error messages

**file:///Users/Qt/program/experiment_apps_and_libs/qmlTest2/main.qml:23:1: module “QtQuick” is not installed import QtQuick 2.1 **

I am stuck staring at a blank white screen with no information on what I am doing wrong.
No document, current document is almost useless because the bugs of macdeploy haven't fixed since Qt5.0.1, and I have no idea
when they would fix it(maybe never get fixed).
no information telling me which dylib I need.It is highly frustrating!
Anybody know how to deploy QtQuick2 apps on mac os x?

If this keep going, maybe I better keep on using QWidget, atleast I don't have to suffer the deployment trouble again.
I am pretty surprise they spend a lot of times to develop QtQuick2 but do not release a useful document to teach us
how could we deploy the apps on their targeted platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer.
Thanks for miks131, MaximAlien and lasconic.

Remember to enter a correct qmldir, else the macdeploy would
not copy the QtQuick2 and QtQuick folder into the bundle

[work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475788/qt-5-1-and-mac-bug-making-macdeployqt-not-working-properly/17591828#17591828)