# QT Quick (QML) assemble mac-.bundle -> not a dynamic library error when using macdeployqt

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qtquick2

I struggle with this for weeks now and hope someone finds this useful or knows an answer. 
- I use QT 5.7 and QT 5.8 and the error occurs on both versions.

I have a QT Quick 2.0 application which I build as a dynamically linked .bundle application on a Mac using macdeployqt.

I call macdeployqt with the following parameters:
%{buildDir}/imageDatabase.app -qmldir=%{buildDir}/../UserInterface/ -always-overwrite -verbose=2

The working directory is $QTDIR/bin because macdeploy needs to be run from inside the QT-Installation directory as I learned here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/59030/solved-macdeployqt-problem/6

The following error occurs when I try to run the application:

- Double-click: The app opens and the icon appears in the bar on the bottom but besides that nothing happens
- Starting the app from Terminal:

Output

```
Machine:MacOS MyName$ ./tool 
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component qrc:/main.qml:1 plugin cannot be 
loaded for module "QtQuick": '/Users/thorstenbux/DAQRI/gitHub/artoolkit6/Source/Utilities/ImageDBSerialiser/build-ui/imageDatabase.app/Contents/PlugIns/quick/libqtquick2plugin.dylib' 
is not a valid Mach-O binary (not a dynamic library)
```

- Calling `file` on the library in question reveals the following

`Machine:MacOS MyName$ file /Users/myname/client/gitHub/tool/SDK/Applications/tool.app/Contents/PlugIns/quick/libqtquickcontrolsplugin.dylib
/Users/myname/client/gitHub/tool/SDK/Applications/tool.app/Contents/PlugIns/quick/libqtquickcontrolsplugin.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dSYM companion file x86_64`

looks like it is loading the debug libraries.

macdeployqt error message is the following:

```
ERROR: Could not parse otool output: "/Users/myname/DAQRI/gitHub/tool/Source/Utilities/tool/build-tool-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_clang_64bit-Release/tool.app/Contents/PlugIns/quick/libqtquick2plugin.dylib:\n"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution in the QT forums. It looks like the macdeployqt has a severe bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57265

You need to call `macdeployqt` without the `-always-overwrite` option. 
Many thanks to Andy Shaw who posted that here:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57265?focusedCommentId=346168&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-346168

Comment: I ran into the same exact problem and this solved it. Thank you!